# jQuery change and click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Binding events to an element should be something like:

```
$( document ).on( 'change', '#mySelect', showEvent );
$( document ).on( 'click', '#mySelect', showEvent );

function showEvent() {
  console.log( event.target );
}
```

But by doing a simple test as shown below, binding the *change* and *click* events to the object **mySelect** they are triggered on different elements (*change only by changing the select and the click by clicking anywhere on the document*).

```
var mySelect = $( '#mySelect' );

$( document ).on( 'change', mySelect, showEvent );
$( document ).on( 'click', mySelect, showEvent );

function showEvent( event ) {
  console.log( event.target );
}
```

Two questions:

1. How does the *change* event work? By the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) it shouldn't work because the selector must be a string:

> A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event.

2. It souldn't work but, if the *change* works, why doesn't the *click*?

Comment: `$( document ).on( 'change', mySelect, showEvent );` isn't valid. What's the point of delegating an event to the document if you know exactly what element you want to attach it to?

Comment: @Stryner Perhaps the `mySelect` element is dynamically generated within the page (shouldn't be using `document` anyways if it's the case, way too global)

Comment: @Stryner I know that's not valid and for that reason I made the question 1. Ansering to your question, Jeff Noel is right, I have a single page application so the pages and elements are dynamically loaded so the only elements I know are always present are document and body.

Answer (score 2):

> **`selector`**
>   `Type: String`   A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

Taken from http://api.jquery.com/on/

You are using the selector as a jQuery object, this method is mainly using for **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for binding event to dynamically generated element. So you can bind event directly to the jQuery object as

```
var mySelect = $( '#mySelect' );

mySelect.on( 'change', mySelect, showEvent )
        .on( 'click', mySelect, showEvent );

function showEvent() {
  console.log( event.target );
}
```

If it's dynamically generated then remove the `$` wrapping just provide it as string

```
var mySelect = '#mySelect';

$( document ).on( 'change', mySelect, showEvent );
$( document ).on( 'click', mySelect, showEvent );

function showEvent() {
  console.log( event.target );
}
```

Comment: Your correct on your suggestion but my questions are still waiting for answers. Why does binding the change event the wrong way works (it souldn't!!!) and the click doesn't?

Comment: You are not following what jQuery doc suggesting